# Оптимизация запроса с подзапросом в Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql-developer

Здравствуйте. Есть запрос. Отрабатывает в sql-developer 60 секунд. Второй раз запускаю 8 секунд, 3 раз 3.5 секунды. Кэшируется вообщем. Минут через 10 та же история. Наверное за это время кэш падает. Когда этот запрос первый раз выполянется из кода c# на строчке `rdr.Read()` вообще выполняется минут 5-10 rdr - OracleDataReader. Не понимаю что ещё можно упростить в запросе. Всё и так проиндексировано кроме поелей edit_state и primary_date. Вообщем вот запрос и explain plan к нему.

```
SELECT r.id
FROM INTERSHOP.JOURNAL_RECORDS r
WHERE r.edit_state = 0
      AND r.journal_id = 515
      AND r.journal_table_id = 1
      AND
(
    SELECT STRING_VALUE
    FROM journal_field_data f
    WHERE r.id = f.journal_record_id
          AND field_name = 'SERTIF_NUMB'
) = :SERTIF_NUMB 
ORDER BY r.PRIMARY_DATE DESC;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я правильно понял то там где написано full очень много занимает памяти, но там всё проиндексировано. И я немного не понимаю но неужели order by весит ещё больше? Подскажите пожалуйста что тут можно сделать. Я уже даже не знаю что попробовать.

**UPD**
Исправленный вариант запроса:

```
SELECT r.id
FROM INTERSHOP.JOURNAL_RECORDS r
     LEFT JOIN journal_field_data f ON r.id = f.journal_record_id
WHERE r.edit_state = 0
      AND r.journal_id = 515
      AND r.journal_table_id = 1
      AND field_name = 'SERTIF_NUMB'
      AND f.STRING_VALUE = :SERTIF_NUMB
ORDER BY r.PRIMARY_DATE DESC;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А почему LEFT-то? он же чистый INNER получается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Можно использовать 2 варианта.

**Первый**:

```
SELECT r.id
FROM INTERSHOP.JOURNAL_RECORDS r
     JOIN journal_field_data f ON r.id = f.journal_record_id
WHERE r.edit_state = 0
      AND r.journal_id = 515
      AND r.journal_table_id = 1
      AND field_name = 'SERTIF_NUMB'
      AND f.STRING_VALUE = :SERTIF_NUMB
ORDER BY r.PRIMARY_DATE DESC;
```

**Второй**:

```
SELECT r.id
FROM INTERSHOP.JOURNAL_RECORDS r
     JOIN journal_field_data f ON r.id = f.journal_record_id
                                  AND f.field_name = 'SERTIF_NUMB'
                                  AND f.STRING_VALUE = :SERTIF_NUMB
WHERE r.edit_state = 0
      AND r.journal_id = 515
      AND r.journal_table_id = 1
ORDER BY r.PRIMARY_DATE DESC;
```

---

Получить представление об общих принципах оптимизации запросов можно из статей на Википедии:

1. [Семантическая оптимизация запросов СУБД](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%A1%D0%A3%D0%91%D0%94)
2. [Оптимизация запросов СУБД](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%A1%D0%A3%D0%91%D0%94)

---

Почему тут не нужен `LEFT JOIN` - и вообще, **кратко и наглядно о различных вариантах соединений** - на иллюстрации:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]