# Изъять данные таблици подзапросами select

Tags: sql, postgresql

Имеется три таблици, чтобы изъять данные не ид, а целевую информацию использую подзапросы select.
Подзапросы возвращает не больше одного поля, в итоге у меня 5 подзапросов, есть ли другой способ, является ли это правильной логикой.
Вот текст.

```
SELECT applicant.firstName, applicant.middleName,
 (Select name From experience Where experience.id = 
applicant.idExperience) AS contact, 
(Select phone From contact Where contact.id = applicant.idContact) 
AS Phone, 
(Select email From contact Where contact.id = applicant.idContact) 
AS Email

FROM (applicant INNER JOIN contact ON applicant.idContact = 
contact.id) INNER JOIN experience ON applicant.idExperience = 
experience.id;
```

Comment: слышали про [JOIN](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL))?

Comment: Нет, сейчас посмотрю

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/734633/183842

Comment: Inner Join подойдёт?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так, проверяйте

```
SELECT applicant.firstName,
       applicant.middleName,
       e.name AS Contact,
       c.phone AS Phone,
       c.email AS Email
FROM applicant AS a
     INNER JOIN contact AS c ON a.idContact = c.id
     INNER JOIN experience AS e ON a.idExperience = e.id;
```